# docker container not distributing load evenly among assigned cpu s

Tags: docker, cpu-usage, cpuset

I have a contanerized microservice (i.e. running docker container) for which i have assigned 8 cpu cores as resources on docker desktop ( please see attached image). But i suspect that all the cpus (0,1,2...7) do not share load evenly and hence the response time of my tested microservice doesn't get reduced as expected. I have also tried to allocate the cpu's via command `docker run --cpuset-cpus="0-7" -p 8081:8080 myimage-docker` . For each cpu in the cpuset, i want to see it's utilization stats in terms of  % cpu usage. Is there a docker command that let me see all the 8 cpu's utilization at once during the docker container run. Something like ..

```
cpu0 - 12.5%
cpu1 - 12.5%
cpu2 - 12.5%
cpu3 - 12.5%
cpu4 - 12.5%
cpu5 - 12.5%
cpu6 - 12.5%
cpu7 - 12.5%
```

[image: docker Desktop Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can measure how evenly load is spread among CPUs.

Use this command to get a shell inside the Moby VM:

```sh
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1
```

Then run this command:

```sh
mpstat -P ALL 1 100
```

That will measure per-cpu usage every second for 100 seconds. Afterwards, it will display averages for each core.

Comment: i used command like   docker run --rm --privileged --pid=host -p 8081:8080 myimage-docker  . How to find the value of host in  "--pid=host"  .Could you please elaborate.  Moreover, the mpstat -P ALL 1 100   seems a linux command , but i need its windows equivalent command.

Comment: No, I mean type the command as it literally appears above. `--pid=host` turns off pid namespaces. `Moreover, the mpstat -P ALL 1 100 seems a linux command` Docker for Windows uses a Linux VM to run containers inside of. In fact, you do want a Linux command here.

Comment: so you mean i should go inside docker container via ssh .  The command like         
  docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash to get a bash shell in the container and then run mpstat -P ALL 1 100 command. Right ?

Comment: No, I mean you need to get inside the Moby VM, not a container within that VM. See e.g. [here](https://www.bretfisher.com/getting-a-shell-in-the-docker-for-windows-vm/).